# converting big float to varchar SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I am converting some big floats like:

```
61326085092
161569087548
169193968080
208082024640
230160816344
```

after using

```
Cast(@FloatValue as nvarchar)
```

I get:

```
61326100000
161569000000
169194000000
208082000000
230161000000
```

This is really bad... so How can I get exact values??

The query I am doing is:

```
INSERT INTO #someT (id,Value) values('''+Cast(@counterI+1 as nvarchar)+''','''+Cast(@Val as nvarchar)+''')';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the numbers you posted `LTRIM(STR(f,32))` works fine.

```
with floats(f) as
(
SELECT cast(61326085092 as float) union all
SELECT 161569087548 union all
SELECT 169193968080 union all
SELECT 208082024640 union all
SELECT 230160816344  union all
SELECT 230160816344.12
)
select f, CAST(f as nvarchar) as v, LTRIM(STR(f,32)) as s1, LTRIM(STR(f,32,10)) as s2
FROM floats
```

Returns

```
f                      v                  s1             s2
---------------------- ----------------- -------------- --------------------------------
61326085092            6.13261e+010        61326085092           61326085092.0000000000
161569087548           1.61569e+011       161569087548          161569087548.0000000000
169193968080           1.69194e+011       169193968080          169193968080.0000000000
208082024640           2.08082e+011       208082024640          208082024640.0000000000
230160816344           2.30161e+011       230160816344          230160816344.0000000000
230160816344.12        2.30161e+011       230160816344          230160816344.1200000000
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of precision.

Try using [`Float(53)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) or  [`Decimal(38,18)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Are you really using floats? The numbers you posted look like integers...

Comment: you mean (38,18) probably :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Cast(cast(@FloatValue as numeric) as nvarchar)
```

Choose an appropriate `numeric` scale and precision for your case. You will always have this problem with floats and reals, they're inherently imprecise.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more,why you are converting to `numeric` and then all that to `nvarchar`??

Answer (score 0):

Are these always whole values(meaning no decimal points) if so convert to bigint instead

```
declare @f float =230160816344

select convert(bigint,@f)
```